# How to use Option.map and Option.bind to rewrite the multiple null checks?

Tags: f#

How to convert the following code, which uses c# HtmlAgility library, to an elegant style?

```
if node <> null then
  let nodes = node.SelectNodes("//input[@name='xxx']")
  if nodes <> null then
    let first = nodes.[0]
    if first <> null then
      let value = first.Attributes.["value"]
        if value <> null then
          Some value.Value
        else
          None
     else
       None
   else
     None
else
  None
```

Could the following code may work? However, it still not as concise as C# 6's `?.` operator.

```
let toOpt = function null -> None | x -> Some x
node |> toOpt
|> Option.map (fun x -> x.SelectNodes("//input[@name='xxx']"))
|> Option.map (fun x -> x.[0]                                ) 
|> Option.map (fun x -> x.Attributes.["value"]               ) 
|> Option.map (fun x -> x.Value                              )
```

C# 6 version is still much more concise:

```
node?.SelectNodes("//input[@name='xxx']")[0]?.Attributes["value"]?.Value
```

Can `Option.bind` helps?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*FYI F#4 has added [`Option.ofObj`](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6103054-add-option-ofnull-to-help-remove-nulls)*

In F# `null` is avoided for good reasons. When dealing with C# libraries that rely on `null` my general advice would be to provide an F# idiomatic "adapter" on that library.

In practice that might be quite much work and the result might not be as succinct as the C# operator `?.` (leaving aside the argument whether such an operator is a good idea or not).

To my knowledge the F# compiler doesn't support such an operator but if you feel strongly for it you should raise it at: http://fslang.uservoice.com/ . The F# community is friendly but I suspect you will have to argue quite vigorously in order to convince the community that it's a good idea for F#.

Meanwhile; one way to make it slightly more succinct is to create a [computation expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) like this (`getAttributeValue` is what your code will look like):

```
// Basically like the classic `maybe` monad
//  but with added support for nullable types
module Opt =

  let inline Return v : Option<'T> = Some v

  let inline ReturnFrom t : Option<'T> = t
  let inline ReturnFrom_Nullable ot : Option<'T> =
    match ot with
    | null -> None
    | _ -> Some ot

  let inline Bind (ot : Option<'T>) (fu : 'T -> Option<'U>) : Option<'U> =
    match ot with
    | None -> None
    | Some vt -> 
      let ou = fu vt
      ou

  let inline Bind_Nullable (vt : 'T) (fu : 'T -> Option<'U>) : Option<'U> =
    match vt with
    | null -> None
    | _ -> 
      let ou = fu vt
      ou

  let Delay ft : Option<'T> = ft ()

  type OptBuilder() =
    member inline x.Return v       = Return v
    member inline x.ReturnFrom v   = ReturnFrom v
    member inline x.ReturnFrom v   = ReturnFrom_Nullable v
    member inline x.Bind (t, fu)   = Bind t fu
    member inline x.Bind (t, fu)   = Bind_Nullable t fu
    member inline x.Delay ft       = Delay ft

let inline ofObj o =
  match o with
  | null -> None
  | _ -> Some o

open HtmlAgilityPack

let opt = Opt.OptBuilder()

let getAttributeValue (node : HtmlNode) (path : string) : string option =
  opt {
    let! nodes  = node.SelectNodes path
    let! node   = nodes.[0]
    let! attr   = node.Attributes.["value"] 
    return! attr.Value
  }


let html = """
<html>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <body>Yellow <div name='Test' value='Stone'>Div</div></title>
</html>
"""

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let doc = HtmlDocument ()
  doc.LoadHtml html
  let r = getAttributeValue doc.DocumentNode "//div[@name='Test']"
  printfn "Result: %A" r
  0
```

Comment: Can anyone elaborate "leaving aside the argument whether such an operator is a good idea or not"? Could it has a better way to do it? Since nullable cannot be removed from c# now.

Comment: In C# or any other language that promotes/allows the usage of nullable types I think `?.` is one of the better compromises. In idiomatic F# one shouldn't use `null`. However, `?.` could be useful in F# for `option` types but I think the preferred idiom is lifting.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the maybe monad in Fsharpx

```
maybe {
  let! node = toOpt node
  let! nodes = toOpt node.SelectNodes("")
  let! first = toOpt nodes.[0]
  let! value = toOpt first.Attributes.["value"]
  return value.Value
}
```

This will result in `None` if any one is null, or `Some value.Value` if not.

**Note** If you read it the whole way through, FuleSnabel's solution is actually better, as it lets you get rid of the `toOpt` everywhere and you can have it just be

```
opt {
  let! node = node
  let! nodes = node.SelectNodes("")
  let! first = nodes.[0]
  let! value = first.Attributes.["value"]
  return value.Value
}
```

The only reason to choose this one over that, would be if you really just want to limit your project to the standard workflow builders defined in Fsharpx, rather than defining your own customized ones (which you can just copy and paste from that answer).